# How do you call an uncurried function with unit in ReScript/ReasonML?

Tags: reason, bucklescript, rescript

Say that I have an uncurried function like:

```
let echo(. a) = a;
```

I can call this funcition fine with most literals like:

```
echo(. 1)
echo(. "Hello")
```

but when I am trying to call it with void, I get an error:

```
echo(. ()) //This function has arity1 but was expected arity0
```

As a workaround,  I can do this:

```
let myArg = ()
echo(. myArg)
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Nope–this is the recommended way.

Comment: Hi @Yawar, where is this recommended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like this version as well:

```
echo(. ignore())
```

that way I don't need the dummy value workaround

Edit: This version is also now part of the docs: https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/function#uncurried-function

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to call an un curried function that takes one parameter with no arguments because that is what `()` means right. The only reason it works with
`echo(. myArg)` is in this case the compiler is declaring an un initialized variable called `myArg`  and passing that to echo.
EDIT: you can look at what I mean at [re-script playground here](https://rescript-lang.org/try?code=DYUwLgBCDGAWD2EC8EAUA6CBDAlMgfNgNwBQZokA1sqnkoTAhhAEQCyWAzvPACYs4SFCAFsAngEEATgHNkaQcM406DOImbjpMnEA)

```
let echo = (. a) => a;


let k =() => echo(. "String")
let myArg = ()
let s =() => echo (. myArg)
```

generates

```js
// Generated by ReScript, PLEASE EDIT WITH CARE
'use strict';


function echo(a) {
  return a;
}

function k(param) {
  return echo("String");
}

function s(param) {
  return echo(undefined);
}

var myArg;

exports.echo = echo;
exports.k = k;
exports.myArg = myArg;
exports.s = s;
/* No side effect */
```

Comment: I don't think that calling a function with unit is the same as calling the function without arguments:

`()` is the only literal of the `unit` type and I would expect `()` to be a valid argument for a function with signature `'a -> 'a`. For example, in OCaml, I can write either of the following functions: `let f a = a` and `let g(a) = a` and I can call them with the `()` literal. Both functions will return `unit`.

Indeed, even in rescript, I can define a function `let f (a) => a;` and `f(())` will return a unit. The question is why can I not do the same when the fucntion is uncurried

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a known issue in rescript. See: https://github.com/rescript-lang/rescript-compiler/issues/3429